# return CGRect on selector causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect, cgpoint

I've the following code:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Does not crash
    //[self performSelector:@selector(dummyRectValue)];

    // Does not crash
    [self performSelector:@selector(dummyPoint)];

    // Crash
    [self performSelector:@selector(dummyRect)];

}

- (NSValue*) dummyRectValue
{
    return [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
}

- (CGRect) dummyRect
{
    return CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

- (CGPoint) dummyPoint
{
    return CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
}

@end
```

Currently, calling `[self performSelector:@selector(dummyRect)]` causes a crash.

Any help understanding what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It will be easy to answer if you provide some log details from console when the crash happened.

Comment: This code works for me..

Comment: This code can´t work.

Comment: For me it worked on a 64-bit device (iPad Mini Retina) but crashed on a 32-bit one (iPhone 5) and a simulator (both 32 and 64-bit). I think we might be dealing with an "undefined behavior" here.

Comment: See the following statement in the docs for `performSelector`: *"The aSelector argument should identify a method that takes no arguments. For methods that return anything other than an object, use NSInvocation."*

Answer (score 2):

perfomSelector is a NSObject method. You can find this in Apple doc:

```
   - (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector
```

You can see, it only returns objects (id), and you are trying it returns a C structure (CGRect)

You can do this:

```
   [self dummyRect];
```

Comment: More specifically, the docs for `performSelector` state the following: *"The aSelector argument should identify a method that takes no arguments. For methods that return anything other than an object, use NSInvocation."*

Answer (score -1):

In objective-C you can not return CGRect. so you have to CGRect convert into NSValue.
so you get the crash report.
This is a fundamental limitation of Objective-C — a variable cannot sometimes hold an object and sometimes a primitive value. The best workaround is to return an NSNumber or NSValue object wrapping the real value you want to return.

Comment: To help clarify: `performSelector:` has a return type of `id`, meaning an Objective-C object. If you call `performSelector:` on a method that returns a non-void, non-Objective-C value then the behaviour is unpredictable.

Comment: The question is: why a method can return `CGPoint` (which is also a primitive value) but crashes when returning `CGRect`.

Comment: That was my point but I guess that if the behaviour is unexpected sometime it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is absolutely false. Of course you can pass a CGRect as a parameter. And nothing about the OP's code involves passing a CGRect as a parameter.

Comment: @user3691662, maybe you can edit your question so it's more clear what you are asking about?

Answer (score -1):

in objective-C you can not send CGRect as a parameter, so you need convert CGRect to NSValue.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Does not crash
    //[self performSelector:@selector(dummyRectValue)];

    // Does not crash
    [self performSelector:@selector(dummyPoint)];

    // Crash
    [self performSelector:@selector(dummyRect)];

}


 //Return CGRect as NSValue
    - (NSValue *)dummyRect
    {
        return [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
    }
```

Comment: Untrue. Of course you can pass a CGRect as a parameter. Besides, the OP's code never passes any CGRect parameters. This make no sense.

Comment: That was my solution too. Thanks for the help.